# How do I get the value of an attribute in a model method before submitting in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs

Let's say I have an attribute :year_of_birth for example and another field :age (readonly), I fill in the year_of_birth. And I make a method in a model to calculate the age, how does the age get populated in the view?

Comment: Do you want a ruby on rails only answer? Because this could be done with a small javascript code.
I don't really see how to compute the age in ruby before even submitting the form.

Comment: @victorFink What is the JS answer? :-)

Comment: You could make a short snippet to get the value of the field and populate the next field after doing some quick computations. I can't really make an answer now because I don't know what is contained in the attribute `:year_of_birth`. Is it a string (i.e '05/07/1991') or just an int (i.e 1991)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a short code snippet I did that should set you up on the right path (using javascript, but no ruby on rails as mentioned in the comment).

`document.getElementById("date").value` gets the value of the element of id "date". You just take the date (I assumed it was just the year of birth) and subtract it to 2020.

```
Date of birth: <input type="int" id="date">
Age: <input type="int" id="age">

<p>Click the button to get the age!</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("age").value = 2020 - document.getElementById("date").value;
}
</script>
```

This is just a basic script and won't be available in a few months as we will be in 2021 so I will let you find how to get the current year in javascript. It's also not perfectly accurate because it doesn't take into account the month/day of birth but you get the idea!

I hope this helped you, and tell me if something's not clear or not working the way you wanted.

EDIT: Oh, I forgot to mention but this code executes after you click on the button, which might not be really user friendly (depends on what you're doing, really!). If you want to make the function executes as soon as the field is populated, it will requires few modifications.

If you want to display the age as soon as the year of birth change, you can add the `onchange` event to the input like this:

```
Date of birth: <input type="int" id="date" onchange=myFunction()>
Age: <input type="int" id="age">

<p>Fill the first area with a year to get the age!</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("age").value = 2020 - document.getElementById("date").value;
}
</script>
```

The `onchange` event will fire as soon as you press enter or click outside of the textarea.

Comment: hi @victoFink is it also possible to do without a button onClick? I was thinking more of a onchange of year_of_birth